# 'Manually' unlock an InfoPath form in SharePoint

Tags: .net, sharepoint, office-interop, infopath

We have a solution in which we use SharePoint 2007 to 'store' InfoPath forms in a FormLibrary. We've created a .NET client application which uses InfoPaths FormControl to open and display the forms to the end-user.

When the application shuts down normally, we close() the FormControl and a HTTP 204 (Unlock) is sent to SharePoint, which probably releases a lock it put on the form in question. However, when the application doesn't shut down normally (eg a crash of some kind), we find that the form cannot be opened anymore because it is 'locked by another user'.

This lock isn't of the "normal" Check-out type btw!

How can I circumvent this issue, or how can I have the lock released?

Comment: It might be worth asking this over at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com - not that it doesn't make sense here, but there might be some expertise there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS recommends waiting 10 mins or rebooting the server.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899709/en-us

Sometimes (mostly) that won't work so try out this code.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93965/Force-SharePoint-Document-Unlocked-Checked-In

Comment: I'll give this a shot and will let you know if it works for me!

Comment: Will work, but we made our our client application not crash anymore. So no longer necessary.